# Update Package causes Win 7 deployment to fail

Tags: windows-server-2012, deployment, windows-update, mdt-2012

For whatever reason our Win 7 deployment hasn't been kept up to date with new updates and I've started adding them as packages. (I know I can create a new image but it's not viable at the moment). Problem is, it's throwing this error when I import the updates from 2011

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/174215

I can't see where in any of the logs it specifies package installation so I can't tell which one it's having issues with. Does it break it down in a log I'm missing or is there another way to figure out where it's getting stuck bar adding them one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [log files](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/05/08/mdt-2010-amp-2012-my-deployment-failed-what-and-where-are-logs-i-should-review.aspx) that you will need are only in the X: drive while booted into Windows PE, as the packages are installed into the offline image during the Offline Servicing pass. There is an easy way to collect all the log files in MDT, and that is by using the SLShare setting in the deployment share rules. SLShare is detailed in the MDT help files, but basically, you create a folder in your deployment share (Logs) and then set SLShare=\servername\deploymentshare$\logs. This setting will create a folder (inside the logs folder) with the same name as the computer and copy all the log files into that folder, including the ones from the X drive.

The DISM.log or the CBS.log should have something related to this and are located under X:\Windows\logs

Hope this helps,

Comment: It's not so much a problem finding the logs but finding the info on what it'sx failing on. I've had a good look through them all and don't find anything specific. I wasn't aware I could collect them in this manner though I'll try and figure out how to get it working with our custom setting setup.

Comment: @crimsonfox The DISM.log or the CBS.log should have something related to this.
Also, that screenshot you linked shows that Windows XP SP3 is being installed...

Comment: The screenshot was just one I grabbed off the net that had the same error. I am installing Win 7, don't worry, I didn't overlook that :p I'll check those logs when i'm back in the office on Monday, cheers.

Comment: Big thanks, it looks like a memory issue. Didn't click when it was some of the older machines doing it. Found the errors in the DISM log just where you said.

Comment: @Crimsonfox Fantastic! Glad you figured out the issue.